# Optional Widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, dsl, widgetkit

How to make an optional widget in Swift? `WidgetBundle` uses `@resultBuilder`, so I think we can do something similar to SwiftUI:

```
// SwiftUI example
if showText {
    Text("Optional text")
}
```

And here's what I want to get working:

```
struct MyWidgetBundle: WidgetBundle {
    let enableTestWidget: Bool = ...

    // Compile error: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; 
    // please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)
    var body: some Widget {
        Widget1()
        Widget2()
        if enableTestWidget {
            TestWidget()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Have you tried the code block? What happened? Did you get an error message? Did it not work?

Comment: @Paulw11, the code block in question produces the compile error. I'll add it to the question.